# phpunit --configuration phpunit_myapp.xml

Tags: xml, continuous-integration, phpunit, gitlab

I am abit new to Gitlab CI/CD..

So i have been following [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/php.html)  to create a working cicd and my yml file is working fine with the cicd. But i wanted to create some testing for the php version however i have now encountered an error

```
    Running with gitlab-runner 10.8.0 (079aad9e)
  on test_cicd runner fe9d0c92
Using Docker executor with image php:7.1 ...
Pulling docker image php:7.1 ...
Using docker image sha256:########## for php:7.1 ...
Running on runner-fe9d0c92-project-19-concurrent-0 via j317456.servers.jiffybox.net...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 9b50afd edit job name
From http://134.119.30.114:10080/Toughblue/wordpress
   9b50afd..bebb7da  php_test   -> origin/php_test
Checking out bebb7da2 as php_test...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ bash ci/docker_install.sh > /dev/null
+ apt-get update -yqq
+ apt-get install git -yqq
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
+ curl --location --output /usr/local/bin/phpunit https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   161  100   161    0     0    475      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   476

100 2721k  100 2721k    0     0  4392k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 4392k
+ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpunit
+ docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
$ phpunit --configuration phpunit_myapp.xml
Could not read "phpunit_myapp.xml".
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

when i run the pipeline or when i up date i get that error.. and obcous the first thing that came to mind was where is the phpunit_myapp.xml because i did not create one .. i have failed to find something that explains what and where that file should be if i have to create one or even how. so i would like to get some help on how to solve this.

Any help that points me to the right direction is welcome

Comment: What is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you need to create this config file when you want to use it
- The XML file contains information about what to test and possible config like e.g. a Bootstrap file
- You can run `phpunit` without configuration file but you need to use parameters

For more information head to https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.1/configuration.html.